# Interlock and backfeed setup with NEMA L6-20

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, generator

Am starting to put a generator setup together.  I'm planning on setting up an interlock and backfeed breaker into my panel with an outdoor receptacle for the gen to plug into.  The issue is this.  My generator is older(its an old garden way with a cast kohler engine, 5500 and runs like a top), and is setup with a NEMA L6-20 for the 220 which I'm planning on using--it also has two standard nema 5 outlets.  This means it is straight 220...so, can I just wire the whole thing 3 wire, no problem?  meaning in the panel, the 2 hots to the backfeed breaker and the grd to the grd bus bar?  Am I missing something, or do I need the neutral?
Thanks in advance for any input![image][image][image]
[image]

Comment: Well, with a NEMA 6 connection, your two hots will be 240V across, but with no neutral to stabilize them, your two 120V legs won't necessarily be 120V.  They might be 130V and 110V... They might be  200V and 40V... Might be 230V and 10V.  That could change minute by minute.    Is that something you can live with?

Comment: Does your generator not have a NEMA 14 (four prong) receptacle whatsoever?

Comment: @Harper    Thanks, interesting-sounds like that could be a problem and fry things plugged into the 110 outlets....  That appears to be how the main power seems to be coming into the house as well, a 3 wire setup, with a braided copper ground going from the ground bus bar to a well feed pipe.   The house was built in 1960.  Its an old Square d QO series panel with the main setup as a 2 pole 100 am breaker on the left leg, lowest spot.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel nope, just theL6-20 and the nema 5's :./

Comment: On your service entrance, that third bare wire is actually the neutral. Power companies don't supply ground as a rule.

Comment: @Harper  appreciate the responses. ...Sounds like I'm screwed unless I can rewire the gen plug to an L14-20....or I'm running two extension cords to through wall recepticles and setting up seperate "generator" outlets for the well pump/furnace, etc.  Guess I could cut those wires I need and install correct male/female plugs where convenient so I could just unplug form service power, and plug into the gen power outlet..  A little more work running wire and such, but might be a good solution for now.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Harper the braided bare copper is the neutral? I thought it was the ground and the third leg from the power company was the neutral?  I have 3 coated wires coming in from the pole.

Comment: @woodsVT sorry, I misunderstood. You are right.  I was thinking it's common for the power company to bring neutral across the poletop as a bare wire, heck it's often the steel messenger!  But on the service entrance it will be insulated.

Comment: I would say if the generator's design has the NEMA 6 hots bused with the 120V receptacles' hots, then I wouldn't see a big problem with tapping neutrals in the same way and bringing that to a NEMA 14.  Be careful with neutral-ground bonding, that should be present in mobile generator use and absent in home power use.  If you can't get rid of it, you need a 3-pole transfer switch, backfed breakers won't do.

Comment: @Harper, thanks!  I"m going ot pull the gen model numbers when I get home tonight and see if I can find a wiring diagram and specs...It's old...but in awesome shape.  Ugh, really hoping not to have to go to a 3-pole transfer swtich, at that point I might just wire an old fuse box I have as a 120 to some outlets for things and run the nema l6 from the gen with an extension cord and add a nema l6 plug into the well powere just before the pressure switch.  Nothings ever easy is it unless you have unlimited funds, ha!

Comment: @woodsVT -- yes, the generator's wiring diagram would be quite helpful :) if you find it, posting it here would help us figure out if the retrofit option's feasible

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel diagram is above. the generator is a northstar 5500bdg 120/240.  The wiring diagram is above.  I found the manual as ell which states it requires a copper grounding rod, which leads me to believe it is not bonded at the gen.  Its a 4 wire stator from the lol of it and the wire harness.  What do you think? Can I convert to l14-20?  Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Do you still want/need the NEMA 6-20 receptacle for other purposes? Do you still want to be able to use this generator for portable power, for that matter, or do you plan to dedicate it as a standby power source?

Comment: This will pretty much be for just backup power,but I dont want to ellliminate the 120 outlets so I can still used them if needed.  I was honestly surprised when I read in the manual a grounding bar was needed when running the generator hooked up to the house, or as a portable generator.  Both are specified uses in the manual found here: https://www.northerntool.com/images/downloads/manuals/165913.pdf

Comment: so there are 4 wire coming from the stator/harness, 2 black 2 white that plug into a plastic harness.  the 2 white are bonded and attached to the 120 outlet.  green grd s are attached to screw at center of generator frame internal.  are the two wites just neutral? can I just jump from that contact point to the neutral plug on a newe l14?  new diagram above.  THanks.

Comment: Can you tell me how the wires are attached to the existing receptacles?

Answer (score 1):

Running the house off the L6-20 receptacle (without the neutral) would be almost sure to start wrecking things on your 120V circuits in short order, blowing light bulbs, refrigerator, etc.  And at the worst possible time, during some emergency.

Since there are 120V receps you know there's a 120V tap in there that can be used to supply line-to-neutral loads.  However there's a chance it is too small to carry the full neutral load for this application.  I am not sure, but from that wiring diagram but it looks like the neutral tab on the 120V receptacle is the neutral-ground bond.

I think it would be possible to modify the wiring and install a L14-30R receptacle, but it wouldn't be a modification I'd be comfortable making.  The alternative would be to use a transformer between the generator and the backfed breaker, but at that point maybe you just buy a different generator better suited for the application .

Answer (score 1):

### One could put a 14-20R on this instead of the 6-20R, yes

About the only feasible way to use this particular generator to power a house would be to replace the existing 6-20R with a NEMA 14-20R (a P&S 3820 *appears* suitable, but fitment may require modifications to the receptacle yoke ears and/or generator housing).  You'll also need a piece of 12AWG white wire of the appropriate type for use here (a flexing service MTW is what the factory used), a piece of heat shrink tubing, and a suitable splice connector (a 12-10AWG crimp butt splice will do), as well as a suitable crimp tool (preferably of the ratcheting variety).

The wiring changes are as follows:

- The brass and black screws on the new receptacle are wired to the existing B50/B52 and B51/B53 ring terminals
- The green screw on the new receptacle goes to the G50/G51 ring terminal to ground it
- The W51 wire (this is the generator's N/G bond) is cut and the end connected to the ground screw on the receptacle is insulated with shrink tubing, and a 12-10AWG crimp butt splice is used to connect the neutral-screw end to a piece of 12AWG white wire going to the neutral screw on the 14-20R, yielding a *floating neutral* generator suited for powering a house through a transfer interlock.

With all that done, you can button the generator back up, label it as a floating neutral generator (important!), and use it to power your house up.  (If you need bonded neutral functionality, I'd simply make a 14-20P up with a jumper from N to G to replace the existing bond.)